# How to add context menu in Windows 10 UWP on ListView Item?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am working on Windows 10 UWP app and came across a long press menu in Photos app as below

[image: ContextMenu]

Can someone suggest how to create this type of menu in Windows 10?

I checked **PopupMenu** control but it only allows 6 options in the menu.I want to create this menu using C# not XAML.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [Flyout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.flyout.aspx) for this purpose, then in item's datatemplate, define subscripe to event and show your menu. A sample can look like this:

```xml
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Holding="Grid_Holding" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                    <MenuFlyout>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="EditButton" Text="Edit"/>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="DeleteButton" Text="Delete"/>
                        <MenuFlyoutSubItem Text="OtherItems">
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Inside1"/>
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Inside2"/>
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Inside3"/>
                        </MenuFlyoutSubItem>
                    </MenuFlyout>
                </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <x:String>Item 1</x:String>
    <x:String>Item 2</x:String>
    <x:String>Item 3</x:String>
    <x:String>Item 4</x:String>
    <x:String>Item 5</x:String>
</ListView>
```

And the code behind:

```cs
private void Grid_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement senderElement = sender as FrameworkElement;
    // If you need the clicked element:
    // Item whichOne = senderElement.DataContext as Item;
    FlyoutBase flyoutBase = FlyoutBase.GetAttachedFlyout(senderElement);
    flyoutBase.ShowAt(senderElement);
}
```

As a result you should see something like in the picture below.

[image]

Some more help you will also find [at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/dialogs-popups-menus#flyout).

---

Edit after comments.

Generally everything you create in XAML can be created in code behind. If you want to create a *Flyout*, then it can look like this:

```cs
private bool startedHolding = false;
private void Grid_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // simple checkup for holding release for this sample, though this probalby need better handling
    startedHolding = !startedHolding;
    if (startedHolding)
    {
        MenuFlyout myFlyout = new MenuFlyout();
        MenuFlyoutItem firstItem = new MenuFlyoutItem { Text = "First item" };
        MenuFlyoutItem secondItem = new MenuFlyoutItem { Text = "Second item" };
        MenuFlyoutSubItem subItem = new MenuFlyoutSubItem { Text = "Other items" };
        MenuFlyoutItem item1 = new MenuFlyoutItem { Text = "First sub item" };
        MenuFlyoutItem item2 = new MenuFlyoutItem { Text = "Second sub item" };
        subItem.Items.Add(item1);
        subItem.Items.Add(item2);
        myFlyout.Items.Add(firstItem);
        myFlyout.Items.Add(secondItem);
        myFlyout.Items.Add(subItem);
        FrameworkElement senderElement = sender as FrameworkElement;
        myFlyout.ShowAt(senderElement);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks can we create the flyout that you created using c# instead of Xaml?

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar Everything you create in XAML can be created in code behind. In XAML it's just easier to do. See my edit for sample.

Comment: Thanks it works as expected but can we change background colour and foreground colour? Also, can we change placement ?

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar Generally I think you can play little with flyout presenter style and try to show it at specific element (though I haven't played with that much). Finally you can define your own content into general *Flyout* control.

Comment: ok and can you add click event part in your sample c# code? I want to handle click events also and get the menuItem and for which ListViewItem, this menuItem is selected.

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar Just subscribe to suitable events in menuflyout items, I believe you can handle those yourself. As for knowing which item has been selected if you take a look at my answer you will find it in first Grid_Holding - it's commented out. Upon that event just remember its *DataCOntext*.

Comment: using the line that you commented, I am getting the ListViewItem object but how to handle click event?

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar Click event of what?

Comment: when I click on FirstItem, I want to do some actions, then same for secondItem,etc.

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar Have you checked the MSDN or in VS what is available? Those MenuItems has events (like button, including Clicked) to which you can subscribe. Do it the same way as you would have done it for button control.

Comment: I checked. I am not getting Click in VS, getting options like Command but I am not sure how to use it.Something is weird. I am getting Click event in XAML but not in C#

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar From what [I can see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.menuflyoutitem.aspx), *Click* is the first event mentioned. Have you checked `firstItem.Click += ...`?

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar Shurely it's not working on desktop, hence you get no holding event - on desktop use *RightTapped* event for right click.

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar Please do not use comments in cases other than question/answer they should apply to.